# How to take the xpath of first radio button with similar attributes of the following html

Tags: radio-button

### Below is the page source of an html save it in notepad with .html file and take the xpath of the following radio button from the DOM. There are two occurrence of it how to choose one radio button.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<mat-radio-button _ngcontent-oeo-c75="" class="mat-radio-button material-radio-button d-block mat-accent ng-star-inserted mat-radio-checked">
<label class="mat-radio-label" for="mat-radio-32-input">
<span class="mat-radio-container">
<span class="mat-radio-outer-circle"></span><span class="mat-radio-inner-circle"></span>
<input type="radio" class="mat-radio-input cdk-visually-hidden" id="mat-radio-32-input" tabindex="0" name="mat-radio-group-30" value="1500" />
<span mat-ripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-radio-ripple mat-focus-indicator"><span class="mat-ripple-element mat-radio-persistent-ripple"></span></span>
</span>
<span class="mat-radio-label-content">
<span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span>
<div _ngcontent-oeo-c75="" class="col-12 wraper">
<div _ngcontent-oeo-c75="" class="col-md-10"><label _ngcontent-oeo-c75="">Harsh V | **3456</label></div>
<div _ngcontent-oeo-c75="" class="col-md-2">
<mat-icon _ngcontent-oeo-c75="" role="img" aria-hidden="false" class="mat-icon notranslate material-icons mat-icon-no-color" data-mat-icon-type="font">delete</mat-icon>
</div>
</div>
</span>
</label>
</mat-radio-button>
<mat-radio-button _ngcontent-oeo-c75="" class="mat-radio-button material-radio-button d-block mat-accent ng-star-inserted mat-radio-checked">
<label class="mat-radio-label" for="mat-radio-32-input">
<span class="mat-radio-container">
<span class="mat-radio-outer-circle"></span><span class="mat-radio-inner-circle"></span>
<input type="radio" class="mat-radio-input cdk-visually-hidden" id="mat-radio-32-input" tabindex="0" name="mat-radio-group-30" value="1500" />
<span mat-ripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-radio-ripple mat-focus-indicator"><span class="mat-ripple-element mat-radio-persistent-ripple"></span></span>
</span>
<span class="mat-radio-label-content">
<span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span>
<div _ngcontent-oeo-c75="" class="col-12 wraper">
<div _ngcontent-oeo-c75="" class="col-md-10"><label _ngcontent-oeo-c75="">Thamil | **3457</label></div>
<div _ngcontent-oeo-c75="" class="col-md-2">
<mat-icon _ngcontent-oeo-c75="" role="img" aria-hidden="false" class="mat-icon notranslate material-icons mat-icon-no-color" data-mat-icon-type="font">delete</mat-icon>
</div>
</div>
</span>
</label>
</mat-radio-button>
</body>
</html>

has context menu
```

[image]

Comment: This is a wipro interview question

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: //mat-radio-button[1]//input[@id='mat-radio-32-input']